# Set styling on one row without change all rows on a website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I managed to break some pages on a big website, that I am managing. Some pages have a right margin or padding on small devices, that they should not have.

I have a feeling that I made some mess with some rows, because I did not give a row an unique name - so the changes I made is going global on all the pages on the website.

How is the correct unique notation for a row, if I have to change something on a single row and not affect a whole website? I used nr 3 from the below code example. Is that wrong?

```css
.foo.row {
  margin-left: 15px!important;
  margin-right: 15px!important;
}
```

```html
<!-- 1 -->
<div class="row foo">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
</div>
<!-- 2 -->
<div class="row-foo">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
</div>
<!-- 3 -->
<div class="foo row">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign an id to your div and then reference it in your css. Please remember that the id needs to be unique.

```css
.row {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#row2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row" id="row2"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

.foo .row is nesting class

```
<div class="foo">
   <div class="row col-sm-12">
       the style will apply
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row col-sm-12">
   the style wont apply
</div>
```

What you ask is

```
<style>
.foo-row {
  margin-left: 15px!important;
  margin-right: 15px!important;
}
</style>

<div class="row foo-row">
    uses the row style and overrides the foo-row style
</div>
```